# Connecting to a Akamai website - actually not connecting

Tags: akamai

I'm trying to connect to a domain that seems to have Akamai tech.

I can't connect and nor does curl - but the browser does.

So I assume the IP address is not blocked.

Reading up - it seems that Akamai runs some algorithms and doesn't allow connections sometimes.

But since a web browser works (from same pc) - I assume it can be made to work.

Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite wage. Akami WAF will not allow curl unless you have white-listed your IP address. Browser connect is just TCP connection on port 80, 443. Which http method did you try to access and is that method allowed? By default i believe only GET and POST are allowed.

Comment: I'm using GET/POST. I can access from my program on my pc fine but not from my server. I thought the IP might be blocked - so I went thru a proxy and that failed too. Same code works on my pc w/o a proxy.

Comment: can you past a sample request and the error that you are receiving.